# PL SQL procedure declaration / definition

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am new to PL/SQL so just trying to figure out the general flow of creating a package

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE P1 AS
     PROCEDURE PROC1
     (
     );
END P1;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY P1 AS
    //package definition
END P1;
```

Is this the correct way to define the package?

Basically, I am trying to find out whether I can declare the package and define the package body in the same file or would i need to create 2 separate files?

When I try to execute it, I get the error `Encountered the word 'PROCEDURE' when expecting one of the following`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have the specification of the package in a file, and the body in another. Why are you trying to put them in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter for an individual package, but you must declare the specification before the body.

Where you are creating multiple packages it is best to create all of the specifications first because the bodies can then compile even if they reference a different package for which the body has not yet been created.